# Ruby method lookup in regards to globals/scopes

Tags: ruby, methods

I am trying to get a full understanding of how Ruby locates methods/symbols but am struggling when it involves multiple levels, especially the global/file scope.

When calling methods explicitly on a class, there are lots of illustrations on the order in which the classes, and modules included by them are searched (and thus exactly what `super` calls in each case). But when not explicitly calling a method, e.g. a plain `func args` rather than `self.func args` what is the search order?

Why does in my example below, the member method calling `func` find the member method before the global, but `func2` finds the global without `method_missing` being called?
And when the global is instead an module/class/type, why is the member with the same name not found at all?

Is there any official documentation as to exactly what the language does when it encounters "`func`, `func()`, `func arg`" etc. in a method? There is a lot of third-party blogs, but they only really talked about single instances with `include Module` and `class Type < BaseType`.

```
def func; "global func" end
def func2; "global func 2" end

class Test
  def x; func end
  def y; func2 end
  def z; Math end
  def w
    func = "local_var"
    [func(), func]
  end


  def func(arg=nil); "method func" end
  def func=(x); puts "assign func=" end
  def Math; "method Math" end

  def method_missing(sym, *args, &block)
    puts "method_missing #{sym}"
    super(sym, *args, &block)
  end
end

x = Test.new
puts x.x.inspect # "method func", member overrides global
puts x.y.inspect # "global func 2", "method_missing" was not called
puts x.z.inspect # "Math" module, member did not override global
puts x.w.inspect # ["method_func", "local_var"], local variables are always considered before anything else
```

Comment: You can't define methods with capital letters, can you? It wont raise an error at definition, but when you try to call it (try `def Something` instead of an already defined module/class)

Comment: @Ninigi : You can define methods with capital letters, see `Array()` in [`Kernel`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Kernel.html)

Comment: @spickermann uh, well the source is C Code though, not ruby... It's not `def Array`. To be a little clearer with what I meant: You can DEFINE the method, but not call it, because ruby will always assume it is a constant, not a method.

Comment: @Ninigi: Just run `def Foo(string); puts "foo #{string}"; end; Foo('bar')` in IRB. It is possible, it works and there are no errors or warnings - and it is plain Ruby.

Comment: @spickermann ah ok, rubys unanticipated smartness strikes again xD of course you can call the capital letter methods, you just need the brackets :D  learned something today

Comment: While I agree that naming a method as such is against conventions, i didn't think Ruby itself actually cared about names in any context? Isn't that just Rails library magic for autoloading (method_missing override?), and mapping things like ActiveRecord to SQL table schemas and other such library code that cares?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ruby's method lookup algorithm is actually *really* simple:

- retrieve the `class` pointer of the receiver
- if the method is there, invoke it
- otherwise retrieve the `superclass` pointer, and repeat

That's it.

If the algorithm comes to a point where there is no more superclass, but it still hasn't found the method yet, it will restart the whole process again, with `method_missing` as the message and the name of the original message prepended to the arguments. But that's it. That's the whole algorithm. It is very small and very simple, and it *has* to be very small and very simple because method lookup is the single most often executed operation in an object-oriented language.

Note: I am completely ignoring [`Module#prepend`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-prepend) / [`Module#prepend_features`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-prepend_features) since I just don't know enough about how it works. I only know what it does, and that's good enough for me.

Also note: I am ignoring performance optimizations such as caching the result of a method lookup in something like a Polymorphic Inline Cache.

Okay, but here's the trick: where exactly do those `class` and `superclass` pointers point to? Well, they do *not* point to what the [`Object#class`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-class) and [`Class#superclass`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Class.html#method-i-superclass) methods return. So, let's step back a little.

Every object has a `class` pointer that points to the class of the object. And every class has a `superclass` pointer that points to its superclass.

Let's start a running example:

```
class Foo; end
```

Now, we have class `Foo`, and its `superclass` pointer points to `Object`.

```
foo = Foo.new
```

And our object `foo`'s `class` pointer points to `Foo`.

```
def foo.bar; end
```

Now things start to get interesting. We have created a *singleton method*. Well, actually, there is no such thing as a singleton method, it's really just a normal method in the *singleton class*. So, how does this work? Well, now the `class` pointer points to `foo`'s singleton class and `foo`'s singleton class's `superclass` pointer points to `Foo`! In other words, the singleton class was inserted in between `foo` and its "real" class `Foo`.

However, when we ask `foo` about its class, it still responds `Foo`:

```
foo.class #=> Foo
```

The `Object#class` method knows about singleton classes, and simply skips over them, following the `superclass` pointer until it finds a "normal" class, and returns that.

Next complication:

```
module Bar; end

class Foo
  include Bar
end
```

What happens here? Ruby creates a *new* class (let's call it `Barʹ`), called an *include class*. This class's method table pointer, class variable table pointer, and constant table pointer point to `Bar`'s method table, class variable table, and constant table. Then, Ruby makes `Barʹ`'s `superclass` pointer point to `Foo`'s current superclass, and then makes `Foo`'s superclass pointer point to `Barʹ`. In other words, including a module creates a new class that gets inserted as the superclass of the class the module is included into.

There's a slight complication here: you can also `include` modules into modules. How does that work? Well, Ruby simply keeps track of the modules that were included into a module. And then, when the module is included into a class, it will recursively repeat the steps above for every included module.

And that's all you need to know about the Ruby method lookup:

- find the class
- follow the superclass
- singleton classes insert above objects
- include classes insert above classes

Now let's look at some of your questions:

> When calling methods explicitly on a class, there are lots of illustrations on the order in which the classes, and modules included by them are searched (and thus exactly what `super` calls in each case). But when not explicitly calling a method, e.g. a plain `func args` rather than `self.func args` what is the search order?

The same. `self` is the implicit receiver, if you don't specify a receiver, the receiver is `self`. And parentheses are optional. In other words:

```
func args
```

is *exactly the same* as

```
self.func(args)
```

> Why does in my example below, the member method calling `func` find the member method before the global, but `func2` finds the global without `method_missing` being called?

There is no such thing as a "global method" in Ruby. There is also no such thing as a "member method". Every method is an instance method. Period. There are no global, static, class, singleton, member methods, procedures, functions, or subroutines.

A method defined at the top-level becomes a `private` instance method of class `Object`. `Test` inherits from `Object`. Run the steps I outlined above, and you will find exactly what is going on:

- Retrieve `x`'s class pointer: `Test`
- Does `Test` have a method called `func`: Yes, so invoke it.

Now again:

- Retrieve `x`'s class pointer: `Test`
- Does `Test` have a method called `func2`: No!
- Retrieve `Test`'s superclass pointer: `Object`
- Does `Object` have a method called `func2`: Yes, so invoke it.

> And when the global is instead an module/class/type, why is the member with the same name not found at all?

Again, there is no global here, there are no members here. This also doesn't have anything to do with modules or classes. And Ruby doesn't have (static) types.

```
Math
```

is a reference to a constant. If you want to call a method with the same name, you have to ensure that Ruby can tell that it's a method. There are two things that *only* methods can have: a receiver and arguments. So, you can either add a receiver:

```
self.Math
```

or arguments:

```
Math()
```

and now Ruby knows that you mean the method `Math` and not the constant `Math`.

The same applies to local variables, by the way. And to setters. If you want to call a setter instead of assigning a local variable, you need to say

```
self.func = 'setter method'
```

Comment: `def x; self.func2 end` calls `method_missing`, and `def x; func2 end` does not, so there is clearly some difference. And if it was private, wouldn't calling `func2` be disallowed?

Comment: `func2` is private, private methods can only be called without an explicit receiver. So, in `self.func2`, `Object#func2` is not found because it is private, therefore `method_missing` is invoked. I don't get your second question: why would calling private methods be disallowed? What would be the point of private methods if calling them weren't allowed?

Comment: First off, cudos to that answer @JörgWMittag I think it's a nice read for beginners and intermediates like me.

Comment: Second, to @FireLancer s question about the "private" function, maybe we should back off a little from the word private here, since private in Ruby is not as private as in other languages ;) Other than that... I dont really get the question either

Comment: yeah your right about private, my bad. im used to privates not being available to subtypes (can only be invoked if direct by a method of the same type), but in Ruby that is note exactly the case

Comment: So, the thing special about "Math", if just the capitalization of the first letter? Is that the distinction at the technical level (and that classes/modules and constants are generally named with such conventions)?

Comment: pretty much, yes. Whenever you send a message starting with a capital letter, ruby will assume it is a constant, unless (as stated in the answer) you give ruby a clue its a method

Comment: No, it's not a convention. That's the *definition* of a constant in Ruby. A variable that starts with a lowercase letter is a local variable. A variable that starts with an uppercase letter is a constant. A variable that starts with a `$` is a global variable. A variable that starts with two `@@` is a class hierarchy variable. A variable that starts with `@` is an instance variable. Methods aren't allowed to start with `@` or `$`, so there's no problem there, but they are allowed to start with letters, and so you can get ambiguities with constants and local variables which you can resolve …

Comment: … by adding a receiver or an argument list.

Comment: @JörgWMittag ah thanks... I deleted my comment, since it was not different from what you said :)

Comment: Yes you are right about "CONSTANTS", I guess i just never really considered "Module" as being one, but rather its own thing. Knowing the right keyword I found the correct doc page now, I think just a deficiency from when i learned that stuff / resources i used

Comment: @Ninigi By the way, I wouldn't say "private is not as private as in other languages". It is, in fact, *more private*. In Java, for example, one object can access another object's privates if they are both of the same type. In Ruby, an object can only access its own privates, and no others. (Of course, in both languages, once you allow reflection, all of those restrictions fly out the window.)

Comment: id say its just a different type of private, since in Ruby a subtype can access a private of the current instance, but in Java/C++ style it cant (which personally i find useful, e.g. to force the person subtyping my thing to use the setter/manipulator and not play directly with the attribute, but can also see why not being able to do `other_instance.some_private` is good, guess cant have everything)